# BST insertion function in Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, typeerror

I am implementing BST in python and having some trouble on insertion function.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.data = val
        self.Leftchild = self.Rightchild = None


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, val):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(val)
            return self.root
        else:
            if self.root.data <= val:
                self.root.Rightchild = self.insert(self.root.Rightchild, val)
            else:
                self.root.Leftchild = self.insert(self.root.Leftchild, val)
            return self.root
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = Tree()
    for i in range(10):
        tree.insert(random.randint(0,100))
```

I got TypeError on recursive.

```
TypeError: insert() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Isn't `self.root.Rightchild` or `self.root.Leftchild` considered same as `self`?
If my thought is wrong, how can I implement recursive insertion function in this case?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, they aren't considered same as self. If you want to call that method on the instance, you need e.g. `self.root.Rightchild.insert(val)`.

Comment: Or let the insert take 3 arguments... something like (self, obj, val) and change the logic accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should have `insert` take another argument, `root`, and do your operations on that. You'll need to modify the recursive logic too. Have `insert` work exclusively with the `Node` data.
2. You should handle cases where an item already exists. You don't want duplicates put into the tree.
3. In the recursive case, you are calling `insert` on the wrong object.

Also, the two are not the same. `self` refers to the current `Tree` object, and `self.root` refers to the current `Tree`'s `Node` object, and so on.

---

This is how you'd modify your function:

```
def insert(self, root, val):
    if root is None:
        return Node(val)

    else:
        if root.data <= val:
            root.Rightchild = self.insert(root.Rightchild, val)
        else:
            root.Leftchild = self.insert(root.Leftchild, val)

        return root
```

Comment: Then, don't I need to have another instance of `Node()`? to use as root? Is there any method that  I have only two parameters, `def insert(self, val)`?

Comment: @jaykodeveloper You can, but you would have to perform recursion on `Tree`. Right now, your code says - a tree is composed of a node and sub nodes. If you change your code to - a tree is composed of sub trees - then you can do that. Think about it.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one if you need class and its instance

```
import random
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.data = val
        self.Leftchild = self.Rightchild = None


class Tree:

    def insert(self,root, val):
        if root is None:
            root = Node(val)
            return root
        else:
            if root.data <= val:
                root.Rightchild = self.insert(root.Rightchild, val)
            else:
                root.Leftchild = self.insert(root.Leftchild, val)
            return root

    def inorder(self, root):
        if root:
            self.inorder(root.Leftchild)
            print root.data,
            self.inorder(root.Rightchild)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = Tree()
    root = None
    for i in range(10):
        root = tree.insert(root, random.randint(0,100))
    tree.inorder(root)
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps! But I think it is basically same as @coldspeed 's one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def inorder(root):
    if root:
        inorder(root.left)
        arr.append(root.data)
        print root.data,
        inorder(root.right)


def insert(root, data):
    node = Node(data)
    if root is None:
        root = node
    elif root.data >= data:
        if root.left is None:
            root.left = node
        else:
            insert(root.left, data)
    else:
        if root.right is None:
            root.right = node
        else:
            insert(root.right, data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(50)
    insert(root, 30)
    insert(root, 20)
    insert(root, 40)
    insert(root, 70)
    insert(root, 60)
    insert(root, 80)

    inorder(root)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to have `Tree` class and its instance.

Comment: try the next one then